# Does linking adjectives allow you to talk about multiple variations of something?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

For instance, if I want to say:

> *I want to see traditional and modern culture*

I would try to use:

> 近代的{きんだいてき}で伝統的{でんとうてき}な文化{ぶんか}を見たい。

But does this imply the culture I want to see is simultaneously modern and traditional? Or could it mean I want to see both modern and traditional variations of culture as intended?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

近代的で伝統的な文化を見たい sounds to me like you want to see culture which is simultaneously modern and traditional. To say you want to see both modern culture and traditional culture, I would say:

> 近代的な文化と伝統的な文化が見たい。
>   近代的な文化や伝統的な文化が見たい。
>   近代的な文化も伝統的な文化も見たい。
>   or maybe... 近代的な文化も見たいし、伝統的な文化も見たい。